# Cakephp2の環境でSmartyが利用できない

Tags: php, cakephp, smarty

phpのバージョン5.4でCakephp2の環境でSmartyを取り入れたいのですがうまくいきません。

```
Error: The application is trying to load a file from the SmartyView plugin
Error: Make sure your plugin SmartyView is in the app\Plugin directory and was loaded
```

といったエラーが表示されます。どう対応すればSmartyが使えるようになるのか分かっておりません。ご教授お願いいたします。
下記を試してみました。

・https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/releases/tag/v3.1.33
からダウンロードし、フォルダ内にあるlibsフォルダをsmartyに変更。
cakephpディレクトリのvendorsディレクトリに入れる。

・テンプレートのキャッシュを格納するディレクトリを作成。
cakephpのapp/tmp/smarty/compile

・https://github.com/news2u/cakephp-smartyview
からダウンロードし、
SmartyView.php
Helperフォルダ内のファイルを
それぞれViewフォルダに入れる

・bootstrap.phpの中に`CakePlugin::load('SmartyView');`を記載

・\app\View\Input内のindexファイルの拡張子をtplに変更

・以下を実行

```
class InputController extends Controller {

    public $viewClass = 'Smarty';

    public function index()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: 表記したエラー内容からapp\Pluginにダウンロードしたsmarty関連のディレクトリを入れないといけないのかと思っています。しかし、ネットの記事を見てみるとapp\Pluginにダウンロードしたsmarty関連のディレクトリを入れるような記述はないのですが入れるべきなのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app/Plugin に `SmartyView` というディレクトリを作ってそこにプラグインファイルを一式いれるのが正解です。READMEにも app/Pluginディレクトリに移動してから git cloneコマンドでSmartyViewディレクトリに展開するよう記述されています。

以下のようなディレクトリ構造になります。

```
app
|- Plugin
    |- SmartyView
        |- SmartyView.php
        |- Helper
            |- ...
```

参考: プラグインのインストール - 2.x
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/plugins/how-to-install-plugins.html

直接app/View配下に置くというブログなどの記述は、このプラグインの元となったヘルパー単体のライブラリを使用する場合の記述でしょう。

また、こちらのプラグインはいくつかIssueが報告されていますが、放置されているようでしばらくメンテナンスされていないようです。

現在のCakePHP 2.xでは動かないかもしれません。
修正の入ったフォークがいくつかあるようですので、もし動かない場合は下記URLから探してみるとよいでしょう。

https://github.com/news2u/cakephp-smartyview/network